# Using REST to try and get Field Service Detail - InventoryID = SQL error: Multi-part identifier not found

Tags: rest, acumatica

I am getting SQL errors when trying to use REST to get to `FSAppointmentDet.InventoryID`, either as a Field Service service item or as an Inventory Item.

The `InventoryID` field exists in the table, however, it looks like the DACs have been inherited, for example as `FSAppointmentDetService`.

Other fields work, it just seems that the fields with an ID are causing the SQL error.

In this case, the SQL error is a multi-step identifier not found.  Running a SQL Profiler trace and looking at the SQL, it looks like the table has been aliased in one part of the query and not in another.  Obviously this is occurring at a level much lower than we can get to, so looking for a workaround or ideas on how to get the `InventoryID` for Field Service detail records.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when one DAC herits (herits as in class inheritance not extend as in DAC extension) from another DAC without redeclaring it's key fields. The way to fix that is to add the parent keys abstract class fields in the children.

FSAppointmentDetService seems to be missing AppointmentID key declaration. When the ORM builds the SQL query it generates Alias for the herited DAC but it gets confused becaused the key fields of the parent were not all re-declared in the child.

In FSAppointmentDet you have 2 key fields:

```
#region AppointmentID
public abstract class appointmentID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}

[PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
[PXParent(typeof(Select<FSAppointment, Where<FSAppointment.appointmentID, Equal<Current<FSAppointmentDet.appointmentID>>>>))]
[PXDBLiteDefault(typeof(FSAppointment.appointmentID))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Appointment Nbr.")]
public virtual int? AppointmentID { get; set; }
#endregion

#region AppDetID
public abstract class appDetID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}

[PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
public virtual int? AppDetID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

But in FSAppointmentDetService only one of them is redeclared. Notice how it's using 'override' to redeclare compared to FSAppointmentDet which do not override:

```
#region AppDetID
public new abstract class appDetID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}

[PXDBIdentity(IsKey = true)]
public override int? AppDetID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

In this case we can't add field to that DAC though because it's part of the base product. I think it would be possible to create a new DAC that herits from FSAppointmentDetService, add the missing key in there and use that new herited DAC instead of FSAppointmentDetService.

However I don't know if that would be possible when working with Web Services. If not the change will have to be made in Acumatica base product. You could fill a bug report with Acumatica support to have that done in future versions.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation of the problem.